# VK API token expired

Tags: vkontakte-api

Чтобы получить сервисный ключ доступа, выполнил следующий запрос:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=айди&client_secret=мой_ключ&v=5.92&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Выполняется успешно, в response:

```
(
    [access_token] => 84e7dade84e7dade845ec0a47884822efb884e784e7dadedf6a458d2a70dfa1b02e190b
    [expires_in] => 0
)
```

Но дальше при выполнении запроса:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember?group_id=айди&user_id=юзер_айди&access_token=84e7dade84e7dade845ec0a47884822efb884e784e7dadedf6a458d2a70dfa1b02e190b
```

В response приходит ошибка:

```
"error_code":28,"error_msg":"Application authorization failed: access_token has expired"
```

Почему так происходит? Запросы выполнял, как из PHP скрипта, так и из url браузера.

Comment: тоже самое, как это лечиться не знаю, ищу уже второй день

Answer (score 1):

Так я разобрался с этим api и вам **НЕ нужно получать ключ**, а нужно просто взять этот **Сервисный ключ доступа** с этой страницы `https://vk.com/editapp?id=YOUR_APP_ID` и подставить его в параметр `access_token` в url
Например получим id-ы юзеров моей группы:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id=blitz.bint&access_token=<access_token>&v=5.95
```

Остальное по аналогии в документации